# Условие в initialize() (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

В initialize() переопределен метод updateItem в TableView:

```
@FXML private void initialize(){
    answersTable.setRowFactory((param) -> new ColorRow());
    questionColumn.setCellFactory((param) -> new WrapTextTableCell());
    answerColumn.setCellFactory((param) -> new WrapTextTableCell());
    questionColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
                       cellData.getValue().questionToThisAnswerProperty());
    answerColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
                       cellData.getValue().answerProperty());

}

private class ColorRow extends TableRow<Answer> {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Answer answer, boolean b) {
        super.updateItem(answer, b);
        if(!isEmpty()&&verifyModeOn) {
            if (!answer.isRigthAnswer()) {
                this.setStyle("-fx-background-color:lightcoral");
            }
        }
    }
}

private class WrapTextTableCell<S> extends TableCell<S, String> {
    private Text text;
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (text != null) {
            text.textProperty().unbind();
        }
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (text == null) {
                text = new Text();
                if (lineBreakOn) {
                    text.wrappingWidthProperty().bind(getTableColumn().widthProperty());
                }
            }
            text.textProperty().bind(itemProperty());
            setGraphic(text);
        }
    }
}
```

`ColorRow` делает красным строки с неправильными ответами (если переменная `verifyModeOn==true`), а `WrapTextTableCell` делает перенос строк в таблице, если переменная `lineBreakOn==true`.

Если убрать условие, тогда все отрабатывает верно. Если условие оставить, тогда появляются следующие проблемы:

1. `ColorRow` подсвечивает пустые строки зеркально снизу.
2. В случае переключения `verifyModeOn` в момент исполнения программы таблица подсвечивает значения неведомым мне образом.
3. В случае переключения `lineBreakOn` в момент исполнения программы таблица переносит строки также неведомым не образом.

Данные в таблице переписываются заново после смены условия.
Мне кажется, что в случае отключения те ячейки, в которых уже были записаны данные, остаются с теми же параметрами.
Если параметр установить 1 раз в начале исполнения программы, все отрабатывает как надо (помимо п.1).
Если поставить условие в сам метод `initialize()`, ничего не срабатывает вообще.

В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в методе `update` вы не закладываетесь на второй параметр `boolean b`, ну т.е. не совсем корректно переопределяете этот метод. в [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateItem-T-boolean-) для `TableCell` указан пример, как надо переопределять этот метод (обратите внимание на пункт 2)

> Note in this code sample two important points:
>
> 1.We call the super.updateItem(T, boolean) method. If this is not done, the item  and empty properties are not correctly set, and you
>   are likely to end up with graphical issues.
>
> 2. We test for the empty condition, and if true, we set the text and graphic properties to null. If we do not do this, it is almost
>      guaranteed that end users will see graphical artifacts in cells
>      unexpectedly.

Перепишите ColorRow примерно таким образом

```
private class ColorRow extends TableRow<Answer> {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Answer answer, boolean b) {
        super.updateItem(answer, b);
        if (b || answer == null) { //если строчка пустая, то сбрасывает стиль 
            this.setStyle("");
            return;
        }

        if(!isEmpty() && verifyModeOn) {
            if (!answer.isRigthAnswer()) {
                this.setStyle("-fx-background-color:lightcoral");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!